# How to replace link text of advanced search

Tags: 2010, search

I'm using SharePoint Search. How can I replace the text/label of the link to advanced search without touching 14 hive?

Comment: Are you using SP 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the xslt that is used to visualize the result.
That xslt in related to the search core webpart. If you check at the property of that web part you can find a XSLT property.

For some more information take a look at these two posts:
http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-add-custom-value-in-search-core.html

http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-modify-sharepoints-result-page.html

If you look how to customize the SearchboxEx take a look here: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/delegate-controls-small-search-input.html

Comment: I don't want to change search results.

Comment: you have to if you want replace link or customize in whatever way you want

Comment: So there's no way to change a simple label in SearchboxEX Webpart directly?

Comment: oh if you wanna change the SerarchboxEX you need to create you custom delegate control: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/delegate-controls-small-search-input.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that's the way I'll have to go. Do you know where I can get an example for a custom search control.

Comment: from the link of the comment that I wrote :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add a small jQuery script to the master page, check if its on the right page by checking the URL (see example but use your own url) and then edit the label using a $ selector. 2 min job, no heavy handed custom deployable code required and quite simple.

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("/search/default.aspx")) {
   $("a[title='Advanced']").text("My Custom Advanced Label");
}
```

Comment: This won't work in multilingual enviroments.

Comment: Well that wasn't mentioned but to be pedantic, of course it will:

    if(document.URL.indexOf("/search/default.aspx")) {
      $("a[title='Advanced']").text("My Custom Advanced Label");
      $("a[title='Avanzado']").text("Mi Avanzada etiqueta personalizada");
      $("a[title='Fortgeschritten']").text("Mein Erweiterte Benutzerdefinierte Beschriftung");
    }

Or you can even look to add in resx file lang pairs in JS but that's probably a bit too far for a label change.